# Implement DKIM for clients relying email through our servers

Tags: email, dkim

We are an E-mail service provider and properly configured SPF, DKIM and DMARC to authenticate all emails. we have dedicated IP addresses too.

We are allowing our clients to send emails through our servers.

The following setup has been done on the client side.

1. Our SPF record has been included in Client's DNS record (SPF), so that we are authorized to send emails on their behalf.

As far as DKIM is concerned, we are signing the emails and signing domain is our domain.

My question is:

> 1. What should I do, In order to sign email on behalf of the client?
> 2. How do, I implement the whole process?

I have checked SMTP2GO and found out they are asking the client to add a `cname` record to their DNS as follows:

**Host Name:**
selector._domainkey.yourdomain.com

**Value:**
dkim.smtp2go.net.

We would like to do the same. what should be done on our DNS records in order to achieve this?

Another option is adding a `TXT` record to client DNS

**Host Name:**
selector._domainkey.yourdomain.com

**value:**
k=rsa p= 'public key'

We would like to do the same. what should be done on our DNS records in order to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance!

Cheers,

Sundar.